# What does "relu" stand for in tf.nn.relu?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

In its [API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu), it says "Computes rectified linear".

Is it Re(ctified) L(inear)... what is U then?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Re(ctified) L(inear) (U)nit

Usually a layer in a neural network has some input, say a vector, and multiplies that by a weight matrix, resulting i.e. again in a vector.

Each value in the result (usually a float) is then considered an output. However, most layers in neural networks nowadays involve nonlinearities, hence an add-on function that, you might say, adds complexity to these output values. For long these have been sigmoids and tanhs.

But more recently people use a function that results in 0 if the input is negative, and the input itself if that input is 0 or positive. This specific add-on function (or better "activation function") is called a relu.

Answer (score 9):

On top of Friesel's answer, I'd like to add two important characteristics of Relu.

## 1. It is NOT differentiable.

Relu's graph: It's pointy, not curvy.

[image]

It is defined as `f(x) = max(0,x)`
therefore it's not differentiable.

## 2. The derivative of ReLU is very simple! Simpler than sigmoid, which is `x(1-x)`.

```
The derivative of ReLU:
 1 if x > 0
 0 otherwise
```

It's the simplest non-linear function that we use mostly on hidden layers. Think about how easy the backpropagation would be!